# How do you retrieve "the most usual color" from SQL MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I'm struggling with Access homework.
I need to get the "most usual color" using SQL query (Colour, Quantity)
This is what I've got so far...

```
SELECT Color as COLOUR, Car_ID as QUANT
FROM Car
WHERE
```

Comment: GROUP BY and COUNT seems like a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Color 
FROM Car 
GROUP BY Color 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Could you show me how I can get the Most usual color?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 Color `

Comment: SELECT Top 1 Color, Car_ID as QUANT
FROM Car 
GROUP BY Color
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Comment: How do I also get the quantity of the TOP color?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 Color, COUNT(*)`